# How to make table heading full width?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve this table look
How can I make the first heading to fill the entire width? Something like `flex: 1` would do. Also, how can I add border to only elements in the table like on the picture, instead of entire table?

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align:left">Month</th>
    <th style="text-align:center">Savings</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">Savings</th>
    <th style="text-align:center">Savings</th>
    <th style="text-align:center">Savings</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td class="center">$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td class="center">$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need this to look like
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mtgT.png)

Comment: Hi. `Something like flex: 1 would do`, did you just answer your question in the question itself?

Comment: When you put flex on th then the td items don't align to it properly.

Comment: Then explain your question properly, we can't guess what you mean ;)

Comment: use tags like thead and tBody in the table tag and then you can style the tBody to have a border

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like below:

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 3px 5px; /* control the spacing */
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse; /* this is mandatory to correctly use border */
  border-bottom: 1px solid black; /* only border bottom here */
}

th:first-child {
  width: 100%; /* take as much space as possible */
}

tr:nth-child(2) {
  border-top: 1px solid black; /* border top to second tr */
}

tr:not(:first-child) {
  /* right and left to all except the first one */
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align:left">Month</th>
    <th style="text-align:center">Savings</th>
    <th style="text-align:center">Savings</th>
    <th style="text-align:center">Savings</th>
    <th style="text-align:center">Savings</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td class="center">$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td class="center">$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif, could you tell me if it's possible to make the table content box to be 100% height? Even if its empty, I am trying to add height/min-height to 100% but it wont fill for some reson

Comment: @alkantra try `min-height:100vh;box-sizing:border-box` on the table element and don't forget margin:0 on body

Comment: @alkantra yes because they need to fill all the space. You have to control the height of the tr to control the space (like I did with width)

Answer (score 0):

For styling the first raw(table header) there are many solutions fastest one by selecting table first raw

```
table tr:first-child{
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I recommend you to read this article first: [A Complete Guide to the Table Element](https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/)

Comment: not only the first element, I need border around all items except the heading

Comment: Try this out `table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tr:not(tr:first-child){
  border: 1px solid black;
}`